# Simple Search filtered by select tag

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, filter

Here i am trying to make a search query filterd by the select tag values. What correction should I edit in my code?

I tried many ways but I didn't see anything wrong with the code.

```
<label>Filter by:</label>
        <select name="select">
            <option value = "fullname">Name</option>
            <option value = "username">Username</option>
        </select>
            <input type="text" name="keywords" style="width:20%" placeholder="Search...">
            <input style="width:3%" type="submit" name="search" value="GO"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <?php       


        if (isset($_POST["search"])){
            $select = $_POST['select'];
            $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
            if ($query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users WHERE '%{$select}%' LIKE '%{$keywords}%' ")) {

                    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                            echo "<tr>".
                                  "<td>".$rows['fullname']."</td>".
                                  "<td>".$rows['username']."</td>".
                              "</tr>";              
                    }                       
            }


        } else {
            echo "No results to display!";
            echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
    }
        ?>
```

I want the results to display based the select tags. When I submit the form, it displayed nothing.

Comment: @mickmackusa, Stack Overflow should just add that comment to every post tagged with 'sql' and 'php'. The rate of false positives would be small enough be ignored.

Comment: 2 things. 1- Use [parametrized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). 2- Check your query [for errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: Or maybe hammer with something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053466/how-to-display-errors-for-my-mysqli-query

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there are multiple things I could comment on.

```
$select = $_POST['select'];
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
if ($query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users WHERE '%{$select}%' LIKE '%{$keywords}%' ")) {
```

Using the `LIKE` predicate only accepts wildcards on the right-side operand. So you don't need the `%` wildcards on the left.

I assume your form options 'fullname' and 'username' are supposed to be column names. But using single-quotes around the left-side operand `'$select'` will treat it as a string, not a column name. Single-quotes are for string or date literals in SQL, not for identifiers like column names or table names.

So now we should see:

```
$select = $_POST['select'];
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
if ($query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users WHERE {$select} LIKE '%{$keywords}%' ")) {
```

But there's a security issue here, because you can't know that `$_POST['select']` 
will always be a legitimate column name. It's easy for someone to do mischief by sending a POST variable that isn't one of the options in your form. When you copy the form input directly into your SQL query, this is a security vector for attackers to hack your site, because they can manipulate your SQL to do something you didn't intend.

Instead, use query parameters for values, and use whitelisting for identifiers.

```
switch ($_POST['select']) {
case 'fullname':
  $select = 'fullname'; break;
case 'username':
  $select = 'username'; break;
default:
  trigger_error("Not a valid choice to search");
  die();
}
$keywords = "%{$_POST['keywords']}%";
if ($query = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * from users WHERE {$select} LIKE ?")) {
  $query->bind_param("s", $keywords);
  if ($query->execute()) {
    $result = $query->get_result();
    ...loop over result...
  }
```